# TKinter Frame Not Filling in TopWindow

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm encountering a problem. I have a root window(main window) in my code, but right now I'm creating a toplevel window for the root. I want to put a frame within a toplevel window. My problem is that I can't make the frame to fill the whole window. It only acts as a background where the widgets are placed.

```
def booksAvailableOpen():
    ## Creates a new window with all available books
    global books
    global backButton
    books = Toplevel(root)
    books.title("Available books")
    books.lift(root)
    books.geometry("+400+300")
    books.geometry("400x400")

## Frame for toplevel window
booksFrame = ttk.Frame(books, height = 600, width = 600, relief = SUNKEN)
booksFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

testLabel = ttk.Label(booksFrame,text = 'hui')
testLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

## Back button used to destroy window
backButton = ttk.Button(booksFrame,text = "Go back", command = booksAvailableBackButton)
backButton.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

I also can't colour the frames, which is another issue I'm experiencing

Comment: The code flow is not very clear in your question, but you can add argument `sticky=W+E+S+N` in your `grid` method call for your frame to fill in both directions. Read more [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm). And check [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm) to see how you can add `bg` option to your `Frame` for color.

Comment: This question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679006/setting-tkinter-ttk-frame-background-color